# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'navigate("Register")') navigation not working

Tags: navigation, react-native, tabview

following is my code

This is my tab.js => Here i given three tabs (mainly working in first home.js)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
  import { Animated, StyleSheet,View } from 'react-native';
  import { TabViewAnimated, TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';
  import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
  import Qwerty from './Qwerty';
  import Home from './Home';
  //import Login from './Login'

  import type { NavigationState } from 'react-native-tab-view/types';

  type Route = {
    key: string,
    title: string,
  };

  type State = NavigationState<Route>;

   class Tab extends PureComponent<void, *, State> {

    static navigationOptions = {
      header: null
    };

    state: State = {
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        { key: '1', title: 'Home' },
        { key: '2', title: 'Shops' },
        { key: '3', title: 'Bookmark' },
      ],
    };

    _first: Object;
    _second: Object;
    _third: Object;

    _handleIndexChange = index => {
      this.setState({
        index,
      });
    };

    _renderLabel = props => ({ route, index }) => {
      const inputRange = props.navigationState.routes.map((x, i) => i);
      const outputRange = inputRange.map(
        inputIndex => (inputIndex === index ? '#fff' : '#222')
      );
      const color = props.position.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange,
      });

      return (
        <View>
          <Animated.Text style={[styles.label, { color }]}>
            {route.title}
          </Animated.Text>
        </View>
      );
    };

    _renderHeader = props => {
      return (
        <TabBar
          {...props}
          pressColor="#999"
         // onTabPress={this._handleTabItemPress}
          renderLabel={this._renderLabel(props)}
          indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
          tabStyle={styles.tab}
          style={styles.tabbar}
        />
      );
    };

    _renderScene = ({ route }) => {
      switch (route.key) {
        case '1':
          return (
            <Home
              ref={el => (this._first = el)}
              style={[styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#E3F4DD' }]}
            />
          );
        case '2':
          return (
            <Qwerty
              ref={el => (this._second = el)}
              style={[styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#E6BDC5' }]}
              initialListSize={1}
            />
          );
        case '3':
          return (
            <Qwerty
              ref={el => (this._third = el)}
              style={[styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#EDD8B5' }]}
              initialListSize={1}
            />
          );
        default:
          return null;
      }
    };

    render() {
      return (

        <TabViewAnimated
          style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}
          navigationState={this.state}
          renderScene={this._renderScene}
          renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
          onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
         // onRequestChangeTab={this._handleIndexChange}
          lazy
        />
      );
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    indicator: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    label: {
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      margin: 8,
    },
    tabbar: {
      backgroundColor: '#ff6600',
    },
    tab: {
       opacity: 1,
      // width: 140,
    },
    page: {
      backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',

    },
  });

  export default Tab;
```

This is Home.js => It is running well if i am using it directly but not running when using it in `Tab.js`.

```
GoPressed(navigate){
  navigate("Register");
}


render() {
   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    contents = this.state.qwerty.data.map((item) => {
      return (
          <View>   
              {item.p1.shareproductid ? <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.GoPressed(navigate)} style={styles.button}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                    Go
                  </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight> : null }

            <Text>
              {item.p1.content}
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
     });
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {contents}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

I am trying to navigate on `Register` screen after `Go` button pressed, But here it shows me error. I have used same navigation method before they works correctly but here it gives error. please show where i am going wrong?

Done somewhat changes in the code I tried running `Home.js` in other way means not using in tab view then it is running and navigation also works but when i am calling `Home.js` in tab-view i.e in `Tab.js` then it showing error as in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: We need to see the full class and where you are defining your stack navigator, probably the parent.

Comment: Great, now we have more info, but there's no `StackNavigator` instantiation in your code. Where are you defining your routes? Checkout the docs in: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack. You need to call `StackNavigator({Register: {screen: Tab}})` or something like that, there is no StackNavigation reference in the code you posted.

Comment: Also, posting the main entrypoint for the React application might help us understanding your case.

Comment: yes.. i added that routing in `index.android.js` for screens used in app but is it need to give such routing differently for tab-view also?

Comment: can u please tell where to add such different routing for navigating from tab view here i added new question [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250614/navigate-to-another-screen-from-tab-view-screen-not-working)

Comment: I think you should try to explain your question further. Are you trying to use a TabNavigator inside a StackNavigator? Without the contents of your `index.android.js` it's going to be impossible to help you. Maybe try posting some parts of it as Gists on GitHub and link it here. I work with some apps that are using multiple Navigation types from a single perspective, maybe I'll be able to help, but there's not enough information not even about the question itself. What is that you are trying to achieve? How are you defining the routes? That kind of stuff.

Comment: The `props.navigation` is automatically passed to your components by the StackNavigator / TabNavigator. If they are undefined there must be some incorrect definition, or you are using the library in a wrong way, putting components outside of its context.

Comment: As a last resource, you may use the `withNavigation` helper, but in that particular case you should really check your definitions. Check out this link -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/with-navigation

Comment: i changed now the tab-navigation system. As i had used  [`react-native-tab-view`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) but now i am using  [`TabNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) of react-navigation which is working great.

Comment: Great, just some misconfigured libraries then! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render code is incorrect, you are getting the `navigate` from props after the return clause.

Try this:

```
render() {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  contents = this.state.qwerty.data.map((item) => {

    return (
        <View>   
            {item.p1.shareproductid ? <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.GoPressed(navigate)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                  Go
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight> : null }

          <Text>
            {item.p1.content}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
   });
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {contents}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just saw in your comment that you get an error with this, we need to see the parent class. What is the navigation framework you are using?

Comment: I alredy tried it as mentioned in above comment it shwing that error `undefined....` , I am using `StackNavigator` yet not solved.

Comment: You mean StackNavigator from `react-community/react-navigation`? Where are you defining your screens? Post the parent code please, what you already posted is not enough to identify the issue.

Comment: Please help for this,,,

Answer (score 2):

Change this,

```
onPress={() => this.GoPressed(navigate)}
```

with this

```
onPress={() => { this.GoPressed(navigate) }}
```

or this

```
onPress={this.GoPressed.bind(this, navigate)}
```

Also I think

```
 const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

this should be before `map` since you are using navigate inside the `map`

Comment: No i tried it that using navigate before the `map` but it throws error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')`