# navigate to another screen from tab-view screen not working

Tags: javascript, navigation, react-native, tabview

following is my code:- posting full code

index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry, Text, StyleSheet, View, NetInfo, Alert, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
    import Splash from './app/screens/Splash'
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
    import Login from './app/screens/Login'
    import Register from './app/screens/Register'
    import Check from './app/screens/Check'
    import Qwerty from './app/screens/Qwerty'
    import Home from './app/screens/Home'


    var STORAGE_KEY = 'token';
    var DEMO_TOKEN;

    class Splashscreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
         header: null
      };

     async componentDidMount() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        var DEMO_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);

        if (DEMO_TOKEN === undefined) {
          navigate("Login");
        } else if (DEMO_TOKEN === null) {
          navigate("Splash");
        } else {
           navigate("Temp");
        }
      };



      render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return(
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <View style={styles.titlewrapper}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}> Loding... </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const Section = StackNavigator({
       Root: {screen: Splashscreen},
       Splash: { screen: Splash },
       Login: { screen: Login },
       Registerscreen: { screen: Register },
       Temp: { screen: Check },
       Qwerty:{screen: Qwerty},
       Home:{screen: Home},
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('shopcon', () => Section);
```

here i can navigate properly without any error Now,

This is my tab.js => Here i given three tabs (mainly working in first home.js)

```
  import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
  import { Animated, StyleSheet,View } from 'react-native';
  import { TabViewAnimated, TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';
  import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
  import Qwerty from './Qwerty';
  import Home from './Home';
  //import Login from './Login'

  import type { NavigationState } from 'react-native-tab-view/types';

  type Route = {
   key: string,
   title: string,
 };

type State = NavigationState<Route>;

class Tab extends PureComponent<void, *, State> {

static navigationOptions = {
  header: null
};

state: State = {
  index: 0,
  routes: [
    { key: '1', title: 'Home' },
    { key: '2', title: 'Shops' },
    { key: '3', title: 'Bookmark' },
  ],
};

_first: Object;
_second: Object;
_third: Object;

_handleIndexChange = index => {
  this.setState({
    index,
  });
};

_renderLabel = props => ({ route, index }) => {
  const inputRange = props.navigationState.routes.map((x, i) => i);
  const outputRange = inputRange.map(
    inputIndex => (inputIndex === index ? '#fff' : '#222')
  );
  const color = props.position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange,
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.Text style={[styles.label, { color }]}>
        {route.title}
      </Animated.Text>
    </View>
  );
};

_renderHeader = props => {
  return (
    <TabBar
      {...props}
      pressColor="#999"
     // onTabPress={this._handleTabItemPress}
      renderLabel={this._renderLabel(props)}
      indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
      tabStyle={styles.tab}
      style={styles.tabbar}
    />
  );
};

_renderScene = ({ route }) => {
  switch (route.key) {
    case '1':
      return (
        <Home
          ref={el => (this._first = el)}
          style={[styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#E3F4DD' }]}
        />
      );
    case '2':
      return (
        <Qwerty
          ref={el => (this._second = el)}
          style={[styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#E6BDC5' }]}
          initialListSize={1}
        />
      );
    case '3':
      return (
        <Qwerty
          ref={el => (this._third = el)}
          style={[styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#EDD8B5' }]}
          initialListSize={1}
        />
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

render() {
  return (

    <TabViewAnimated
      style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}
      navigationState={this.state}
      renderScene={this._renderScene}
      renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
      onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
     // onRequestChangeTab={this._handleIndexChange}
      lazy
    />
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
indicator: {
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
label: {
  fontSize: 18,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  margin: 8,
},
tabbar: {
  backgroundColor: '#ff6600',
},
tab: {
   opacity: 1,
  // width: 140,
},
page: {
  backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',

},
});

export default Tab;
```

This is Home.js => It is running well if i am using it directly but not running when using it in Tab.js

```
GoPressed(navigate){
    navigate("Registerscreen");
  }

  render() {
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      contents = this.state.qwerty.data.map((item) => {
        return (
            <View>   
                {item.p1.shareproductid ? <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.GoPressed(navigate)} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                      Go
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableHighlight> : null }

              <Text>
                {item.p1.content}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
       });
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          {contents}
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
```

I am trying to navigate on Register screen after Go button pressed, But here it shows me error. I have used same navigation method before they works correctly but here it gives error. please show where i am going wrong?

How to navigate to any other(not these three screens of tab-view ) screen from tab-view?

I tried running Home.js in other way means not using in tab view then it is running and navigation also works but when i am calling Home.js in tab-view i.e in Tab.js then it showing error as in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: how about you put your code up on https://snack.expo.io so that its easier to test

Comment: @nathvarun sorry... but i dont know about how can i run it on snack cause i am rendering here many external files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're navigating to the wrong screen name. 
This should do it.

```
GoPressed(navigate){
    navigate("Registerscreen");
  }
```

I honestly can't test out your code as it'll take too much time. 
How about you check out this simple working example of what your looking for and match it with your code.

Go the **Settings tab** and then you can click on the **button** to navigate to the other **Registerscreen** which is not in the Tabs.

https://snack.expo.io/HJ5OqS5qZ

Comment: sorry about it i mistakely done that `Register` it is originally `Registerscreen` now i have modified it, but main problem is not this. How to can i give routing to navigate from tab-view to another screen?

Comment: Just checkout the snack link and see if thats the output your looking for.

Comment: i cheked it..It is working what i need but I am using `react-native-tab-view` here [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view). In your snack u have used Tab-navigator,  i am again in trouble that how that rounting be used in my project

Comment: Just changed the navigation system from react-native-tab-view to TabNavigator now its working